# Adsys can't fetch GPOs from Active Directory

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, ldap, gpo, spnego

Bad, maybe not understandable, english ahead.

On Ubuntu 22.04, I've followed the Wiki tutorial and verified all steps on Integration Ubuntu Desktop whitepaper. Currently using SSSD backend, I can log with Active Directory users however when adsys is installed I can't fetch GPOs. In this version the error is:

```
ERROR Error from server: error while updating policy: can't get policies for "ubuntu": can't download all gpos and assets: one or more error while fetching GPOs and assets: can't download "ubuntuRoot": can't check if ubuntuRoot needs refreshing: no GPT.INI file: cannot open smb://addc01.domain.com.br/SysVol/domain.com.br/Policies/{DF072E7E-6F2F-46D1-A90F-699415F72F2E}/GPT.INI: invalid argument
```

It happens when using `adsysctl update -m` or `adsysctl update username@domain.com.br /tmp/krb5c_getentId_randomdnumber` and just `adsysctl update` too.

I've upgrade the machine to 22.10 and the error changed to:

```
ERROR Error from server: error while updating policy: can't get policies for "ubuntu": failed to retrieve the list of GPO (exited with 1): exit status 1
Failed to bind - LDAP client internal error: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
Failed to connect to 'ldap://addc01.domain.com.br' with backend 'ldap': LDAP client internal error: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
Failed to open session: (1, 'LDAP client internal error: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER').
```

After upgrade to 23.04 the error persist same as the above.

Full info 22.04 (-vvvv verbose):

```
INFO No configuration file: Config File "adsys" Not Found in "[/home/jzprates /root /etc /usr/sbin]".
We will only use the defaults, env variables or flags.
DEBUG Connecting as [[2504:109556]]
DEBUG New request /service/UpdatePolicy
DEBUG Requesting with parameters: IsComputer: true, All: false, Target: ubuntu, Krb5Cc:
DEBUG NormalizeTargetName for "ubuntu", type "computer"
DEBUG Check if grpc request peer is authorized
DEBUG Authorized as being administrator
DEBUG GetPolicies for "ubuntu", type "computer"
DEBUG Getting gpo list with arguments: "--objectclass computer ldap://addc01.domain.com.br ubuntu"
DEBUG GPO "ubuntuRoot" for "ubuntu" available at "smb://addc01.domain.com.br/SysVol/domain.com.br/Policies/{DF072E7E-6F2F-46D1-A90F-699415F72F2E}"
DEBUG Analyzing "assets"
DEBUG Analyzing "ubuntuRoot"
INFO No assets directory with GPT.INI file found on AD, skipping assets download
ERROR Error from server: error while updating policy: can't get policies for "ubuntu": can't download all gpos and assets: one or more error while fetching GPOs and assets: can't download "ubuntuRoot": can't check if ubuntuRoot needs refreshing: no GPT.INI file: cannot open smb://addc01.domain.com.br/SysVol/domain.com.br/Policies/{DF072E7E-6F2F-46D1-A90F-699415F72F2E}/GPT.INI: invalid argument
```

Full info 23.04 (-vvvv verbose):

```
INFO No configuration file: Config File "adsys" Not Found in "[/home/jzprates /root /etc /usr/sbin]".
DEBUG Connecting as [[58811:006019]]
DEBUG New request /service/UpdatePolicy
DEBUG Requesting with parameters: IsComputer: true, All: false, Target: ubuntu, Krb5Cc:
DEBUG NormalizeTargetName for "ubuntu", type "computer"
DEBUG Check if grpc request peer is authorized
DEBUG Authorized as being administrator
DEBUG GetPolicies for "ubuntu", type "computer"
DEBUG Getting gpo list with arguments: "--objectclass computer ldap://addc01.domain.com.br ubuntu"
ERROR Error from server: error while updating policy: can't get policies for "ubuntu": failed to retrieve the list of GPO (exited with 1): exit status 1
Failed to bind - LDAP client internal error: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
Failed to connect to 'ldap://addc01.domain.com.br' with backend 'ldap': LDAP client internal error: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
Failed to open session: (1, 'LDAP client internal error: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER')
```

Additional info:

Domain Controller and machine are on the same subnet without firewall on any level;
Domain Controller is a Windows Server 2019 updated to the last security version;
Both machine and user are on the same OU with "no heritage" enabled and just one policy added to permit username@domain.com.br to become root;
The info header directory is "/home/jzprates" on both logs because I've collected them using the local account using "sudo adsysctl update -m -vvvv";
If I disable Adsys login on pam-auth-update, Ubuntu creates a homedir and enter correctly with domain users.

Comment: Follow this on: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adsys/+bug/2024377
and https://github.com/ubuntu/adsys/issues/733